# Prove that an inequality holds under given assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I try to prove that an expression `eval` of 4 variables (`c,` `L`, `r1`, `r2`) is negative when all of the variables are positive. I want `Simplify` to return `False`, but it does not return a `True`/`False` result. Are there any ways that I can fix it or any other functions that I can use in this situation?

```
eval = 
  -(( L + c r1 r2 + Sqrt[L^2 + c^2 r1^2 r2^2 - 2 c L r2 (r1 + 2 r2)])/(2 c L r2));

Simplify[eval > 0, {r1 > 0, r2 > 0, c > 0, L > 0}]
```

> ```
> L + c r1 r2 + Sqrt[L^2 + c^2 r1^2 r2^2 - 2 c L r2 (r1 + 2 r2)] < 0
> ```

Comment: Take a look at this case `eval /. {r1 -> 1, r2 -> 1, c -> 1, L -> 1}`

Answer (score 2):

As LouisB showed, you have to exclude all parameter combinations, where eval has an imaginary part. That means, the expression under Sqrt may not be negative

```
eval

(* -((L + c r1 r2 + Sqrt[L^2 + c^2 r1^2 r2^2 - 2 c L r2 (r1 + 2 r2)])/(2 c L r2))   *)
```

Get the conditions, where eval is real

```
red1 = Reduce[L^2 + c^2 r1^2 r2^2 - 2 c L r2 (r1 + 2 r2) >= 0 && r1 > 0 && 
         r2 > 0 && c > 0 && L > 0]

(*    r2 > 0 && r1 > 0 && 
        L > 0 && (0 < c <= (L r1 + 2 L r2)/(r1^2 r2) - 
           2 Sqrt[(L^2 r1 + L^2 r2)/(r1^4 r2)] || 
       c >= (L r1 + 2 L r2)/(r1^2 r2) + 
    2 Sqrt[(L^2 r1 + L^2 r2)/(r1^4 r2)])    *)
```

Now show, that for all conditions, where eval is real, eval is at the same time not positive.

```
Reduce[eval >= 0 && red1]

(*   False    *)
```

Get an impression, where eval is real, depending on L

```
 Manipulate[
   RegionPlot3D[
    r2 > 0 && r1 > 0 && 
        L > 0 && (0 < c <= (L r1 + 2 L r2)/(r1^2 r2) - 
           2 Sqrt[(L^2 r1 + L^2 r2)/(r1^4 r2)] || 
       c >= (L r1 + 2 L r2)/(r1^2 r2) + 
    2 Sqrt[(L^2 r1 + L^2 r2)/(r1^4 r2)]), {r1, 0, 6}, {r2, 0, 
   7}, {c, 0, 8}, AxesLabel -> {r1, r2, c}], {{L, 30}, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why when I changed the assumption to eval1<0, the result is not a True result ?                                                                                                 
 In[22]:= Reduce[eval1 < 0 && red1]

Out[22]= r2 > 0 && r1 > 0 &&  L > 0 && (0 < 
    c <= (L r1 + 2 L r2)/(r1^2 r2) - 
     2 Sqrt[(L^2 r1 + L^2 r2)/(r1^4 r2)] || 
   c >= (L r1 + 2 L r2)/(r1^2 r2) + 
     2 Sqrt[(L^2 r1 + L^2 r2)/(r1^4 r2)])

Comment: Reduce[eval < 0 && red1] repeats all the conditions, that have to be fulfill in order to give      True . The folowing code gives the answer you want:  Reduce[ForAll[{r1, r2, L, c}, red1, eval < 0]]   gives  "True"

Comment: It works. Thank you so much :D